# Why is strtok printing only first word?

Tags: c, string, split, scanf, strtok

I am using strtok for converting **string** into **individual words**. I have done the following:

```
int main() {
  char target[100];
  char *t;
  scanf("%s",target);
  t = strtok(target," ");
  while (t!= NULL)
  {
    printf("<<%s>>\n", t);
    t = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The input is a string such as 'this is a string', the output I am getting is`<<this>>`.

Comment: How about `for (t = strtok(target," "); t; t = strtok (NULL, " ")) printf("<<%s>>\n", t);` ? (even though I'm not a huge fan of `<<%s>>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have written `scanf` it will accept string till white space only

> scanf("%s",target);

SO You need to change the way you take input from console

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",target);
```

Comment: Oh forgot that, nice, +1!

Comment: I was going to suggest that -- but you were just too quick `:p`

Comment: I have changed it to 'scanf("%99[^\n]",target)', still printing only <<this>>, ie the 1st word.

Comment: @Tehreem did you see all the answers? Maybe it's time you learn about `fgets()`. :) However, Mohan's suggestion should work.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
scanf("%s",target);
```

to:

```
fgets(target, 100, stdin);
```

since the first won't stop when encounters the whitespace in your input.

Output:

```
this is a string
<<this>>
<<is>>
<<a>>
<<string
>>
```

Notice how the newline [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) stores affects the output. You can simply discard it if you want, like this:

```
fgets(target, 100, stdin);
target[strlen(target) - 1] = '\0';
```

and now the output is:

```
this is a string
<<this>>
<<is>>
<<a>>
<<string>>
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin agree, that's why `fgets()` was the first one that came to my mind.

Comment: Yep, that's why I voted it up (and for the good explanation).

Comment: Aagh, I changed it like u said, to fgets, still same output.. only the 1st word.

Comment: @Tehreem update your question and copy paste the exact code you are using! I assume that you are on a terminal, but that shouldn't be an issue. Oh I now see you got an answer, glad about it. :)

Comment: This is the code i am using now, http://ideone.com/yZTChR and its working. Is it compulsory to set the limit to 99 as in %99?

Comment: @Tehreem and BatCoder, no. It's a good idea, since it safeguards from a large input. However, the code will work, as long as the user's input is less than 100 chars.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to continue using [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), then you can use the below code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char target[100];
   char *t;
   //scanf("%s",target);
   scanf("%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]", target);
   printf("%s\n",target);
   t = strtok(target," ");
   while (t!= NULL)
   {
      printf("<<%s>>\n", t);
      t = strtok (NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/OwfEA6).

Just writing `scanf("%s",target);` will read the input only till the first white space; which is why you get only the first word as the output.  By writing `scanf("%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]", target);`, you are reading 99 characters (including numbers `0-9`, `a-z` or `A-Z` and white space) from the input stream.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Anything wrong with `"%99[^\n]"`? You can still use your *character class*, but you should really use the *field width modifier* to limit the characters read to what will fit in `target` `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it will read only `99` characters.  The OP does not say that the input length is `<=99`.  So I think a generic one would be more helpful.

Comment: Well, not quite `"%[0-9a-zA-Z ]"` will read as many characters as are input (without limit) as long as they are `0-9a-zA-Z `, that's why  `"%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]"` would be an improvement.

Comment: Yep, that is much better. Also, you need not change your answer, but consider the differences between the `"[^\n]"` character class (everything up to the newline) and `"[0-9a-zA-Z ]"` (only *alphanum*). Both can have their place, but if the user entered a `\t` (or some other strange thing users do) the `"[0-9a-zA-Z ]"` wouldn't handle the character.

Comment: Thanks this works...  and doing `"%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]"` takes in 99 characters of type alphanumeric only right?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes, I agree.  Thank you for your guidance. :)